# Хочу изменить код активити с другого активити

Tags: java, android

Пишу тест. Хочу, что бы при прохождении 15 вопроса, на странице MainActivity появлялась кнопка. Есть мысли только что её можно заранее сделать invisible, а потом сменить на visible. Но как это сделать с другого активити не знаю, помогите.

Comment: Вы ведь где-то храните информацию о количестве пройденных вопросов? В БД или ещё как-то (в SharedPreferences, например)? Если да - то просто проверяйте сколько у вас пройдено вопросов и делайте кнопку видимой или невидимой. Если вы не храните - то начинайте хранить. Без этого ничего сделать нельзя (можно, но сложно и неправильно). Из одной активити нельзя менять другую.

Comment: startActivityForResult

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а как тогда делается это?:
В приложении несколько уровней, но что бы открыть 2-ой, надо пройти 1-ый.
Но 2-ой показан, и при этом закрыт, но после прохождения - открывается.

Comment: @AMika, сложно вам что-то сказать, кроме уже озвученного. Судя по вашим комментариям и вопросу у вас или нет хранения данных в программе или вы не знаете, есть ли это. Если хранения данных нет, то у вас в коде может быть какая угодно логика (я могу с ходу пару десятков способов реализации назвать). А раз так - то и нельзя ничего посоветовать - ибо глупо гадать при таком обилии вариантов. Вам надо или описать какой из десятков способов вы используете в логике программы или начинайте хранить данные к-л способом - это сразу решит все проблемы, т.к. данные доступны в любой активити всегда.